# How to turn a list of strings into one string in ruby?

Tags: ruby, list

How should one go about taking a list such as
`["1","2","3"]`
and turning it into a string such as 
`"123"`?

Comment: You should accept Matthew's answer. He answered first. The rest is basically the same.

Comment: @Mischa: Matthew wasn't first (fact check), but his should have been accepted.

Comment: @Linuxios - He *was* the first: 2013-02-26 14:31:47. You answered 2013-02-26 14:32:03.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
list.join()
```

If you want the numbers seperated by commas, or something else, use:

```
list.join(',')
```

Answer (score 8):

You can use [`join`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html#method-i-join):

```
["1","2","3"].join
```

Comment: It's amazing how the three identical answers play out votewise. But +1 for including a link to the docs! (and good pair of first answers! Welcome to SO!)

Comment: @Linuxios, all answers are basically the same. Matthew was first, so he deserves the upvotes and his answer should be accepted IMO. The rest might as well be deleted.

Comment: @Mischa: Not deleted. I answered first by a few seconds. He still deserves the accept though.

Comment: @Linuxios - No *he* answered first by a few seconds.

Comment: We were both trying to help, so no worries! Special thanks to Mischa who edited my answer to be cleaner and in a code block!!

Comment: @Mischa: Whatever. It doesn't matter.

Answer (score 2):

Just for fun, most people don't know we can also do:

```
%w[1 2 3] * ''
=> "123"

%w[1 2 3] * ','
=> "1,2,3"
```

It's more idiomatic to use `join` but occasionally using `*` is helpful.

`*` is also used to repeat strings:

```
def output_header(str)
  puts str, '-' * str.length
end

output_header('Output: some string being output')
output_header('Output: some other string being output')
```

Which outputs:

```
Output: some string being output
--------------------------------
Output: some other string being output
--------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 1):

just use a simple join: `["1","2","3"].join`

result : `"123"`

Answer (score -1):

`["1","2","3"].to_s` will cast the array to a string.  Google "ruby Array" for more Array functions.  Other common classes are String, Hash, Object, etc.  Googling and reading through the docs will help you answer most questions like this pretty quickly.

Comment: `.to_s` doesn't give the desired result.

Comment: Ah, according to the docs this function has been changed to be an alias for inspect in later versions, which is different than what it does in the version I'm using.  `"#{["1","2","3"]}"` should have the correct effect, `.join`, as was suggested by several other people, will also work.

Comment: No, that doesn't have the correct effect either. Both will result in `"[\"1\", \"2\", \"3\"]"`. The only correct answer is `.join`.